# Change the 'Other...' user label in Mac OS X Lion Login Screen

Tags: mac, osx-lion, login

On the Lion login screen the 'Other...' user appears when the root user is enabled, users are hidden and/or the computer is a member of a domain.

Is there anyway to change the label of 'Other...' to something else? Such as 'Domain Users'.